# Common disk on a Dual Boot between Windows 11/Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, shared-file

I want to dual boot on my computer and I’ve seen that it’s possible to share files between windows and Ubuntu. The point is I don’t think I quite understand how it works, could someone explain to me please ? What’s the problem with the NFTS and fat32 files, the common disk between the two systems how is it working ? Cheers.

I’ve done the dual boot, Ubuntu is not working very well, when I am rebooting or shutting down my computer on Ubuntu, it’s getting stuck on the Ubuntu loading screen and I have to shut it down manually. The point is: I don’t have the acces of the ressources from windows to Ubuntu and same problem on the other way. The disk I’ve shrinked for Ubuntu is on an NFTS type. When I’ve download Ubuntu I’ve put ext4 so Ubuntu can get set up. Now I think that I have to create an other partition that both of the systems could read. Is that possible ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.